# Can I give a role permission to configure one (and only one) block?

Tags: 7, users

Right now, I see that the administrator role has a premission called `administer block`. I would like to offer that permission to another role, but only for a specific block, not all of them. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

try the content access Module for drupal 7.x might be exactly what you need

Comment: It doesn't look like it offers per-block permissions, but I'll give it a try sometime next week and give you some feedback. By the way, I noticed it is still in beta for Drupal 7, have you tried it in 7 yet?

Comment: yes works fine in drupal 7.. i would also look into display suite module its a bit of a learning curve but when coupled with Panels it allows custom block regions and custom blocks as fields. IT also gives you the power to edit the permissions of each block you create using the module.

Comment: Do you need to display a block for a particular roles or do you need to give the access of block(operations) to a particular role